# Comparar dos strings desordenadas en php

Tags: php

Como puedo comparar si dos strings tienen los mismos elementos aunque estén desordenados?

Ejemplo:

```
{"307":["106","99"],"305":"95","306":"98","308":"12-8-99"}

{"306":"98","305":"95","307":["99","106"],"308":"12-8-99"}
```

He intentado convertirlo en array para compararlo pero no funciona.

```
    $optionv = preg_split("/[,]+(?![^\[]*\])/", $optionv);
    $optionv2 = preg_split("/[,]+(?![^\[]*\])/", $optionv2);

    if (sort($optionv) == sort($optionv2)){};
```

Un saludo, gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido Jossman, presioná [edit] y agrega lo que has intentando. Nosotros no hacemos la tarea de los demás, sino que los ayudamos encontrar una solución a partir de su código. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour].

Comment: Tu pregunta ya existe en el sitio en inglés mira:
[How to know if two arrays have the same values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229197/how-to-know-if-two-arrays-have-the-same-values)

Comment: ok gracias voy a revisarlo

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Como son Json los tratamos como lo que son
$optionv='{"307":["106","99"],"305":"95","306":"98","308":"12-8-99"}';
$optionv2='{"306":"98","305":"95","307":["99","106"],"308":"12-8-99"}';
//obtenemos 2 arreglos
$optionv=json_decode($optionv,true);
$optionv2=json_decode($optionv2,true);

//Creamos una funcion para traspasar el arreglo bidimencional a un arreglo normal 
$limpia=function($v){
    if(is_array($v)){
        sort($v);
        $v=implode(',',$v);
    }        
    return $v; 
};

// Convertimos
$optionv=array_map($limpia,$optionv);
$optionv2=array_map($limpia,$optionv2);

// Comparamos y retonamos el conteo de las diferencias de uno y otro array
$res=count(array_diff($optionv,$optionv2));

// tratamiento final
if($res==0){
    echo "son iguales";
}else{
    echo "No son iguales";
}
```

Comment: El script no es preciso si, por ejemplo, `$optionv2` tiene más elementos que `$optionv`. Un `count()` inicial a ambos arrays puede paliar este problema.

Comment: hay muchos caminos para llegar a Roma.

Answer (score 0):

No es tan sencillo comparar ese array de forma simple, como esa cadena es un json, propongo importarla a array y luego y crear una función para hacer las comparaciones:

```php
function compare_arr($arr1, $arr2) {
    if(count($arr1) != count($arr2)) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach($arr1 as $k1=>$v1) {
        if(!array_key_exists($k1, $arr2)) {
            return false;
        }
        $v2 = $arr2[$k1];
        if(is_array($v1) and is_array($v2)) {
            sort($v1);
            sort($v2);
        }
        if($v1 !== $v2) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

El primer `if` verifica la longitud de los array, si son distintas, devuelve `false`.
Dentro del `for`, el segundo `if` verifica si la llave del `$arr1` **no existe** en `$arr2`, si es así, devuelve `false`.
El tercer if verifica si ambos valores son array, si es así entonces ordenarlos con `sort($array)`
Finalmente, el último if compara si **son diferentes** los valores, ya sea entre valores simples o arrays ordenados. Si es así, devuelve `false`.

Si no entró en ninguno de los `if` que tienen `return`, entonces los arrays, sea las cadenas iniciales en formato json, son iguales.

Prueba:

```php
$json1 = '{"307":["106","99"],"305":"95","306":"98","308":"12-8-99"}';
$json2 = '{"306":"98","305":"95","307":["99","106"],"308":"12-8-99"}';
$jobj1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$jobj2 = json_decode($json2, true);
var_dump(compare_arr($jobj1, $jobj2)); // <-- true
```

Haciendo solo un cambio en un valor:

```
$json2 = '{"306":"98","305":"95","307":["99","106"],"308":"12-8-99"}';
// ---------- se cambio 106 por 107 ------------^
var_dump(compare_arr($jobj1, $jobj2)); // <-- false
```

Answer (score 0):

(presuponiendo que te refieres siempre a la comparación de **json** desordenados)

Este código convierte los **strings** en **arrays**, que son recorridos y ordenados, y finalmente convertirlos de nuevo a **json** para terminar comparándolos.

Usa una *función recursiva* para ordenar sea cual sea el nivel en que se encuentren los **arrays**, y así, cuando lo reconvertimos a **json**, deberían mantener exactamente el mismo orden, pudiendo comparar los strings con una simple igualdad.

En este ejemplo he anidado varios **arrays** más. El código está autocomentado:

```php
<?php
$json1 = '{"303":["106",["44","33",["11","22"]],"99"],"305":"95","306":"98","308":"12-8-99"}';
$json2 = '{"306":"98","305":"95","307":["99",["33",["11","22"],"44"],"106"],"308":"12-8-99"}';

$arrays = [
    json_decode($json1, true),
    json_decode($json2, true)
];

// recursiva: parámetro por referencia
function ordenar(&$array)
{
    // ordenamos
    sort($array);

    // sacamos clave y elemento
    foreach ($array as $clave => $el) {
        if (is_array($el)) {
            // ordenamos de forma recursiva
            ordenar($array[$clave]);
        }
    }
}

$str = [];

// recorremos los array que viene de json
foreach (array_keys($arrays) as $clave) {
    ordenar($arrays[$clave]);
    $str[$clave] = json_encode($arrays[$clave]);
}

// comparamos json finales
echo ($str[0] !== $str[1])
    ? "No son iguales: false\n"
    : "Son iguales: true\n";
```

En este ejemplo devuelve **Son iguales: true**.